# MariaDB non-root users passwords reset after server restart

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I create a user and set a password. It works okay until mariadb server restarts.
After I run 'service mysqld restart' only root mysql user continues to work. When trying to use any other user I get an error: Connect failed: Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

So every time after server restart I have to log in as root and execute query: SET PASSWORD FOR 'username'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('passw').

Also if after setting password I execute query 'FLUSH PRIVILEGES' the password gets lots again.

Server version: 10.2.12-MariaDB-10.2.12+maria~xenial-log - mariadb.org binary distribution

Comment: sounds like your install is broken i advice you to reinstall.MariaDB

Comment: Maybe your hard disk is full or mysql process doesn't have privileges to write to database files?

Comment: @Raymond Nijland Thanks, after reinstall all works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled MariaDB as Raymond Nijland suggested. It fixed the problem.